# Set 2 default variables in a tcl procedure

Tags: tcl, proc

When defining a procedure in tcl like the one below, How can I call the proc defining just a and c? Is there any way to do this?

```
proc test1 { a {b 2} {c 3} } {
   puts "$a $b $c"
}
```

Comment: Nope. You cant skip the argument.

Comment: Is there any way to provide 2 or more default values whatever it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one technique, a bit messier that what you're hoping for but not too messy:

```
proc test1 { args } {
    # set the default values
    array set values {b 2 c 3}

    # todo: validate that $args is a list with an even number of items

    # now merge in the args
    array set values $args

    # and do stuff with the values ...
    parray values
}

test1 a 10 c 14
```

You sometimes see applications use this technique where the array keys have a leading dash, to look like options:

```
proc test1 args {
    array set values {-b 2 -c 3}
    array set values $args
    parray values
}

test1 -a 10 -c 14
```

Comment: In case it needs to be said, `a` can still be a required parameter by using `{a args}`. If one still wants `a` to appear in `values`, use (e.g.) `array set values [list a $a b 2 c 3]`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Glenn and Peter, I joined your posts and I got

```
proc test1 { a args } {
    array set valores [list a $a  -b 2 -c 3]
    array set valores $args
    puts "$valores(a) $valores(-b) $valores(-c)" 
}
```

which solved what I wanted.

So now I can call

```
> proc 12 -c 8
> 12 2 8
```